# Provide Menu in Module

Tags: 8, navigation

I am looking for a way to provide a whole menu (no menu items) within a module. I could find many ways how to do that in D7, but I really would like to da that in D8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put the menu in the folder `config/install` of the module.

An example from the devel module:

**/config/install/system.menu.devel.yml**

```
id: devel
label: 'Development'
description: 'Links related to Devel module.'
langcode: en
locked: true
```

Then you can place the menu link items for this menu in `*.links.menu.yml` in the root directory of the module.

**Edit:**

As mentioned in the comment from @mradcliffe, some background info might be helpful. Menus are configuration entities. The storage of the configuration is for performance reasons in the database, but they were at the beginning of D8 in yaml files. If you sync the configuration to the harddisk you will find the configuration in a set of yaml files. You can put any of these yaml files in the config/install folder of your module. But you have to remove the uuid line, because the uuid is only valid for the installation you have exported the yaml file from. The menus are in `system.menu.*.yml`.

Comment: It would be helpful to explain that menus are configuration entities, and that is why they need to be added to `/config/*` directories.

Comment: Thanks for that, I will check it out tomorow, but sound good!